# How to construct box with connected line from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm trying to draw a line **dynamically** with given json.

i heard it can be done easily with **flexbox**.

**Note: solution with flexbox is most welcome**

**here is what i'm expecting:**

[image]

**i have this json:**

```
var path = [
  [{name:"S",color:"blue",parent:true}]
  [{name:"A",color:"blue"},{name:"B",color:"blue"},{name:"C",color:"blue"}],
  [{name:"D",color:"blue"},{name:"E",color:"blue"}],
  [{name:"E",color:"blue"},{name:"F",color:"blue"}]
]
```

**Tried something like this:**

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  max-width:1200px;
  margin-top:100px;
  justify-content:center;
  margin-left: 214px;
}
.container .items{
  padding: 40px 70px;
  border:1px solid rgba(15,30,200,.6);
  margin-right: 90px; 
}

.line{
  flex:1;
  position:relative;
  left:40px;
  width:100px;
  border-top:1px solid red;
  display:inline-block;
}

.line {
    flex: 1;
    position: relative;
    left: 161px;
    width: 91px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(15,30,200,.6);
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="items"><span class="line"></span>A</div>
  <div class="items"><span class="line"></span>B</div>
  <div class="items"><span class="line"></span>C</div>
  <div class="items">D</div>
</div>
```

Please help me thanks in advance !!!!!!!!!

Comment: This might help: https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/QPKzYQ

Comment: everyone please check unbelievable answer by Sir @trincot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it with CSS and JavaScript. You need a container element in your HTML, and the data object, and the CSS and JavaScript function do the rest.

I extended your sample data with another "root", so to show what that gives:

```js
function drawPath(selector, path) {
    function draw(directions) {
        return $("<div>").addClass(directions).append($("<div>"),$("<div>"),$("<div>"),$("<div>"));
    }

    let lineNo = -1;
    let lines = [];
    for (let row of path) {
        line = [];
        lineNo++;
        for (let obj of row) {
            if (obj.parent) lineNo = 0;
            line.push(draw("east west"), $("<div>").addClass("box").text(obj.name));
        }
        if (!lineNo) {
            lines.push(line.slice(1));
        } else if (lineNo == 1) {
            lines[lines.length-1] = lines[lines.length-1].concat(line);
        } else {
            lines[lines.length-1][1].addClass("south");
            lines.push([$("<div>"), draw("north west")].concat(line.slice(1)));
        }
    }
    let length = lines.reduce((len, line) => Math.max(len, line.length), 0);
    let pct = (100/length-0.01).toFixed(2);
    // pad lines to the longest length
    lines = lines.map(line => Array.from({length}, (_, i) => line[i] || $("<div>")));
    // flatten
    let $elems = $([].concat(...lines).map(jq => jq.css({flexBasis: pct + "%"}).get(0)));
    $(selector).append($elems);
}

// Demo
var path = [
    [{name:"S",color:"blue",parent:true}],
    [{name:"A",color:"blue"},{name:"B",color:"blue"},{name:"C",color:"blue"}],
    [{name:"D",color:"blue"},{name:"E",color:"blue"}],
    [{name:"E",color:"blue"},{name:"F",color:"blue"}],
    [{name:"S",color:"blue",parent:true}],
    [{name:"A",color:"blue"},{name:"B",color:"blue"},{name:"C",color:"blue"},{name:"D",color:"blue"},{name:"E",color:"blue"}],
    [{name:"E",color:"blue"},{name:"F",color:"blue"}]
];

drawPath(".container", path);
```

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    color: rgba(15,30,200,.6);
}
.container>* {
    flex: 0 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 50px;
}
.box {
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
}
.container>div>div {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    height: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.north>div:first-child {
    border-right: 1px solid;
}
.south>div:nth-child(3) {
    border-right: 1px solid;
}
.east>div:first-child {
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
.west>div:nth-child(2) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```